# Submitting PDF XFA forms using javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

Here's my situation.  We have a web based application that renders an editable PDF within an html page that allows the user to fill in the PDF form.  There is a submit button on the HTML page (outside of the PDF) that the user can click to submit the PDF input to the server.

This is all working now with standard Acroforms.  The way it works is:

1. The HTML submit button, uses the javascript pdf.postMessage API to send a message to the PDF that it wants to submit the form.

   pdf.postMessage(["submitForm"]);
2. Inside the pdf, there is javascript that receives this message and does this:

   function myOnMessage(aMessage) {
     if (aMessage[0] == "submitForm") {
       var fdf = this.myDoc.exportAsFDFStr(true, true, null, true);
       this.myDoc.hostContainer.postMessage(["saveFdf", fdf]);
     }
   }
3. The host container receives this message and uses javascript/jQuery to post the FDF to our server.

   pdfObject.messageHandler = {
     onMessage: function(msg) {
       if (msg[0]=="saveFdf") {
         $("#fdf").val(msg[1]);
         $("#entryForm").submit();
       }
     }
   }

So this is all working for AcroForms.  But it obviously does not work for XFA LiveCycle forms since those do not support FDF.

What I'm looking for is an equivalent to this line for XFA javascript.

```
var fdf = this.myDoc.exportAsFDFStr(true, true, null, true);
```

Essentially an API call that will allow me to serialize the user input into a single string that I can submit to the server.  I've looked at the XFA javascript documentation, and I'm struggling to understand it well enough to find it.

I see ways to create HTTP buttons on the PDF itself, but that isn't what I want to do since I want my browser to do the post request because I return HTML back.

Can this be done?  Thanks.